# Adding manifest properties to existing jar files with ant

Tags: java, ant

Since the latest java release (7u45), I'm getting tons of errors on third part jar libraries that my webstart application uses, due to newly required manifest attributes being missing:

```
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://site/lib/jh.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://site/lib/jh.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://lib/jh.jar
```

So, I need to run a batch ant task to update the manifest files in each of the 30 or so required libraries before I can use them for distribution.

How can I do this in ant? (preferably without ant-contrib)

PS: I've already fixed all the other 7u45 update crap (code signing, JNLP attribs, etc).

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this.

```
   <for param="jarFile">
        <fileset dir="${webapp.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <sequential>
            <jar update="true" file="@{jarFile}">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Application-Name" value="ABCDEF"/>
                    <attribute name="Codebase" value="*"/>
                    <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions"/>
                </manifest>
            </jar>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

Comment: <fileset> should be surrounded by <path> </path>, otherwise it's a good solution, thanks!

Comment: <for> is an ant-contrib. :(